# Oauth Calls to Twitter API using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter, twitter-oauth, ionic-framework

Am trying to implement a twitter based app in ionic , where I would authorize a user and make API calls based on his authorization. (say reading his tweets)

I currently have used ng-cordova-oauth [cordova-oauth](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth) and i got the oauth_token and oauth_secret, screen_name and user_id for user once he is authorized by twitter.

Now i would want to make API Calls using the above mentioned values using Angular. Can anyone help with making the API call (preferably with Angular $http) or point to any JS library available.

Comment: This may not be the answer you are looking for, but I have not found a plugin that does Twitter auth that works well with Cordova.

Comment: Thats bad news. I even have the oauth_token and secret. Wouldnt there be a straight forward way to call the APIs using those ?

Comment: I noticed oauth.js but i am not sure if  it can be used for apps which uses user authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have utilized ngOAuth to make oauth calls once token is obtained using ng-cordova-oauth.

To Simplify, i have also created a angular module which combines the two steps and makes using twitter API calls a bit easier.(from ionic)

https://github.com/sriram-dev/twitter-OAuth-Lib

Hope it helps!